# Is this a bug in PHP

Tags: php, string

```
<?php

if(stripos('http://cp.uctorrent.com', 'cp.utorrent.com') >= 0){
    echo "Good1";
}else{
     echo "Bad1";
}

if(stripos('http://uctorrent.com', 'cp.utorrent.com') >= 0){
    echo "Good2";
}else{
    echo "Bad2";
}

?>
```

output is

> Good1Good2

whereas it should be

> Good1Bad2

Comment: `var_dump(stripos('http://uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com'))` And stop asking the same multiple times.

Comment: Please format your code for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
utorrent <---> uctorrent
```

i am such an idiot...

it was spell mistake ...

comparing uctorrent with utorrent

sorry every one

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
  if(false >= 0) echo "Good";
  else echo "Bad";
  // this code prints Good
?>
```

It's not a bug, it's a "weird" boolean conversion.

`stripos` returns false when the string is not found, and false converts to 0 in PHP.

Directly from the [documentation](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) (the problem is the other way around) :

> Warning This function may return
>   Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on Booleans for more
>   information. Use the === operator for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

Comment: I don't think it's weird, it's consistent with the automatic conversion used by the language. People should just read the documentation more carefully instead of assuming how functions work.

Comment: @Matteo Riva: reading is boring. It is more simple to create 2 questions on SO

Comment: @Matteo This is why I put weird in quotes.

Comment: THIS WAS SPELL MISTAKE. uctorrent <----> utorrent

Comment: @Wasim I think you didn't understood the answer. The point is your condition will **always** evaluate as true, it is impossible that the else branch will be executed. You must compare the result of stripos with something else.

Answer (score 2):

In case 2 `stripos` returns `false` as the search fails and `false` when compared with `0` returns `true`.

The right way of doing it is to use the identity operator which checks both type and value:

```
if(stripos('http://cp.uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com') !== false)
  echo "Good1";                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
else 
  echo "Bad1";
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manual would help greatly:

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. **Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.**

Answer (score 1):

> If needle is not found, stripos() will return boolean FALSE.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Boolean FALSE in PHP is equivalent to integer 0, which is `>= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether stripos failed to get a match, you need to test for type *and* value with !== or ===, for example:

```
<?php

if(stripos('http://cp.uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com')!==false)echo "Good1";
else echo "Bad1";

if(stripos('http://uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com')!==false)echo "Good2";
else echo "Bad2";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Again, try this and avoid the issues caused by microoptimization function use patterns:

```
if (stristr('http://cp.uctorrent.com', 'cp.utorrent.com')) {
   echo "Good1";
}
else {
   echo "Bad1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below $p has value 'false' (means 0), so it's >=0

```
$p = stripos('http://uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com');
```

You need to check stripos('http://uctorrent.com','cp.utorrent.com') !== false first then get $p (found position) like above...